# Highlight a text in Html using Java

Tags: java, html, jsoup, highlight

I am trying to add highlight to search words in an HTML String in Java.
I am parsing the HTML using JSoup and iterating over each text node to find the search words, then adding **mark** tag around the word.
As I am parsing each node sequentially, there is a case which is getting missed out.
If a text is getting split by a tag, then the word definitely cannot be found by current logic.
Example :

```
<div><span class="A">search sear<span class="B">ch</span></span></div>
```

If search word is **"search"**, then first one will get highlighted, but the second one will miss out.

Is there a way I can highlight `sear<span class="B">ch</span>` without any major change in HTML structure?

Code Logic :

```
 private static void doHighlighting(Node body, List<String> searchWordList, String highlightRgb[]) {
String startTag = "<mark style=\"background-color:rgb("+ highlightRgb[0] + "," + highlightRgb[1] + "," + highlightRgb[2] + ")\">";
String endTag = "</mark>";
for (Node node : body.childNodes()) {
  if (node instanceof TextNode && !((TextNode) node).isBlank()) {
    String nodeText = ((TextNode) node).text();
    Map<Integer, Integer> indexMap = new HashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    for (String searchWord : searchWordList){
      indexMap = StringUtil.patternIndexSearch(searchWord.toLowerCase(), nodeText.toLowerCase(), indexMap);
    }
  //indexMap stores startPosition and endPosition of the searchwords in a String
 //Then adds mark tag here and updates the html
    
  } else {
    doHighlighting(node, searchWordList, highlightRgb);
  }
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please share your code?

Comment: @pcsutar Code basic logic shared.. I am using KMP Search algo to find the words

Comment: Did you ever solve this problem @ProGamer? We are looking for the same

Comment: @qwerty unfortunately No